# Android: Disable or Override OnBackPressed of internel activity

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, back-button, lockscreen

Using Xamarin for Android, I am using a third party component to create a lock screen by PIN on various activities on my app.

When the user logs in for the first time they are prompted to create a pin. This fires off the third party's Activity for pin creation. If the user hits the back button while on that activity it backs out into the home screen of my app and bypasses the pin creation and validation.

**I do not have access to modify the code of the third party's internal activitiy.**

I also am launching the activity via a method call to the component and **not by using the StartActivity** call.

I need a way to disable or Override the onBackPressed event for these internal activities. 
Is there a way to disable the back button for the whole app and then re-enable it when the user returns from the third party component?

Any ideas for how I can disable the OnBackPressed event for an activity I do not have modification rights to?

PS: The component is the Xamarin Lock Screen.

Comment: In your activity you have to be detecting the result of the pin activity somehow. In any case, when this activity closes and your activity is called back, you have to pass throuh onResume() method can't you controll the pin has not beeen added there?

Answer (score 0):

If you could use the 3rdy part component activity as base class for your activity, or extending it creating your own class you could then override the OnBackPressed like this:

```
public class yourNewActivity: ThirdyPartActivityClass{

//...

public override void OnBackPressed()
    {
        if (BackEventEnabled)
             base.OnBackPressed();
     }

}
```

where in your class 
    public bool BackEventEnabled = true; (or false to disable);

Before launching the activity with the method of the component
you could do

```
BackEventEnabled = false;
```

and after

```
BackEventEnabled = true;
```

I don't know if anyway can help you or someone else, even giving a starting point for better ideas or workaround/hack. I hope so.